# How to combine the similar x-axis value in highchart?

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have this high chart :

[image]

and this axis is form by this code:

```
    var xAxis = [{
                    categories: {{ t|safe }},
                    labels: {rotation: -90,
                    style: { fontWeight: 'bold' }},
                        title: { text: ' '}


                },{
                    categories:{{ secondxlabel|safe }},
                    linkedTo: 0,
                    opposite: false,
                    labels: {rotation: -90,
                    style:{color: '#2f10a5'}}

                    }]
                ;
                var yAxis = {
                    title: {
                        text: ' '

                    },
                    plotLines: [{
                        value: 0,
                        width: 1,
                        color: '#050505'
                    }],
                    labels:{
                        style: {
                    color: '#a5110e'
                    }
                    }
                };
```

And I wish to have this kind of x-axis which is all the repeated month will be group into one only:

[image]

Anyone can share me some idea?

Comment: can you add this to jsfiddle.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/W43Zb/351/

Comment: {{ secondxlabel|safe}} = [2016Nov, 2016Dec,2016Dec,2016Dec,2016Dec,2016Dec,2017Jan, 2017 Jan, 2017 jan,...]

Comment: {{t|safe}}=[201648,201649,201650,201651,201652,201653,201701,...]

Answer (score 1):

Use [grouped categories](https://www.highcharts.com/plugin-registry/single/11/Grouped-Categories) plugin for Highcharts.

```
  xAxis: [{
    labels: {
      groupedOptions: [{
        rotation: 90
      }],
      rotation: 0
    },
    categories: [{
      name: 'Group 1',
      categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar']
    }, {
      name: 'Group 2',
      categories: ['Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug']
    }, {
      name: 'Group 3',
      categories: ['Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    }]
  }],
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/e87m6dLv/1/

Comment: But I not able to group this because my x axis value are dynamic actually

Comment: You need to process your data before you render the chart and dynamically create appropriate groups.

Comment: any example can share with me ? because I very new to it and hope that with the example can make me more understand about it

Comment: Can you paste some sample data?